# Adding a Worklight app to an already existing Native app

Tags: native, hybrid, ibm-mobilefirst

First of all, I want to know if it is indeed possible to embed a Worklight application into an already existing Native app. I know that you can add a webview and feed content to a native app from the web, but how would I do that from a Worklight app? Is it possible? Are there any examples of such? I'm racking my brain and to be honest, I have no idea!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you already have a native app and want to add WL hybrid (WebView) container to it, right?

I don't think it's an out-of-the-box option.

The work around that comes to mind is to :

1. Create blank WL app using WL studio
2. Add, let's say, Android environment
3. Build the app to get native project
4. Copy worklight.jar, cordova.jar, assets and main activity class to your native app
5. Open WL activity from #4 when you want it

I didn't test it, but it might work:)

Comment: I'm not sure it'll work but it's a good suggestion, I'll give it a go!